# Nothing happens when running python3 script on mac terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I am using macOS Big Sur ver 11.2.1.
I am studying python and wrote a simple script from youtube. I ran it in the correct directory but nothing happens. How can I fix this problem?

[image: screenshot of visual studio code and terminal]

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than in a screenshot. The issue with your script though is that `computer_guess(10)` is never called because its indentation makes it part of the function. Remove the indentation. To avoid those things, you can end functions without a return value with pass (https://realpython.com/python-pass/).

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @nehalem my mistake. I will post my code next time. and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer_guess(10) needs to be dedented (i.e. one tab space further back)

`computer_guess(10)`

not

`computer_guess(10)`

It's currently inside the function which is why it's not running.